# A field of Radical Sums

Tags: radicals, primitive-roots, computational-algebra

I am dealing with a computation that yields numbers that are sums of radicals of the following form:

$N=\sum_{i=0}^{m}{a_i\sqrt{b_i}}$

Where $a_i,b_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ (rationals). The context is intersection of propagating planes, and centers of inscribed spheres to tetrahedrons (as far as I can tell, they cannot be more simple than a sum of radicals).

I am interested whether each such number can be represented in the most simplest and, most important, unique form (s.t. two numbers $N_1,N_2$ are equal iff $N_1-N_2$ is uniquely represented by $0$). It is easy to show that in fact $b_i \in \mathbb{N}$ since the fraction can be pulled out into $a_i$. But how do I check if a sum is in its simplest form otherwise? (which is the same as asking how to simplify it further).

By simple, I mean that every radical is simple (no squares inside the square root), and that the sum has the fewest amount of summands.

My purpose is it to build a number type of such sums of radicals, for exact computations of the mentioned above. For this, I need it to be an algebraic field.

**Side question 1:** how to test if $N$ is positive or negative as quickly as possible?

**Side question 2:** is there an existing (coded) number type used in practice? I couldn't find any by extensive googling.

**Side question 3:** is the inverse to a radical sum always a radical sum (can be expressed by one)?

Comment: It's not so simple to see that $b_i\in \Bbb N$. What about $\sqrt{3/5}$? Also, $0$ is not a unique representation unless you have some restriction on the $b_i$ ( "unique and square free" is necessary, I don't know whether it's sufficient), take for instance $\sqrt8-2\sqrt2$. Otherwise, interesting question.

Comment: $\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}=\sqrt{\frac{3\cdot 5}{5 \cdot 5}}=\frac{1}{5}\sqrt{15}$. It is always possible since $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$. 
You are right that zero can in fact be something like $0 \times \sqrt{5}$ but this means that it is not a simple representation, since it is rational (I guess another rule would be that rational numbers are represented as purely rational (0 radicand)). Of course, $b_i$ have to be natural numbers anyhow. \\

$\sqrt{8}$ is not simple, since the radicand contains a $4$. (no squares inside the square root = no multiplicity).

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume that the ration $b_i/b_j\in\mathbb{Q}$ is not a square of a rational number. Then the numbers $\sqrt{b_i}$ are known to be linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and therefore there is a uniqueness of representations. Moreover, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{b_i})$ is a field, the inverse of each such number is again of this form.